# Sentence construction while using gerund

Tags: sentence-construction

Can I frame a sentence like this -

> "The Union government's policies have shown results in **picking up investments**  and **showing definite signs of a recovery in the economy**".

Instead of this--

> "The Union government's policies have shown results with **investments picking up** and **the economy showing definite signs of a recovery**".

Comment: what's your opinion about it? what's your doubt? I'm afraid without showing any effort, this'll attract 'close voting'. Also, think of using 'as' in your 2nd sentence. *"....results as investments pick up and the economy shows definite signs..."*

Comment: Dear Maulik, What about first one is it correct in terms of sentence structure?

Comment: I'd avoid it...somehow I consider 'results in' as 'ending in'. For instance, 'uncaring the patients results in negligence" for a doctor.

Comment: No, you really can't... at least, not in this case. It sounds really clunky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order changes the meaning for both phrases, more so the first than the second:

- *picking up investments* - This is equivalent to *acquiring more investments*
- *investments picking up* - This is equivalent to *(existing) investments that are increasing in value*
- *showing definite signs of a recovery in the economy* - This doesn't sound quite right.  First, it sounds like you're trying to say something earlier in the sentence or conversation has directly caused a show of recovery in the economy, such as "Union government's policies," but the meaning of the original sentence is more like "this helped the economy."  Additionally, the repetition of the verb "show" with two different subjects in this sentence makes this sound awkward.
- *the economy showing definite signs of a recovery* - This is the separate idea that the economy itself is showing signs of a recovery, and you are implying that "investments picking up" has helped.

Comment: Thank you. In first sentence, I have tried to use gerund (picking up and showing) as additional information of "investments" and "definite signs of a recovery", so is this not a correct way to show additional information?

Comment: It is, just keep in mind that the word order is important for subjects/objects of gerunds.  "What bothered me was Mark running all the time." means something different than "What bothered me was running Mark all the time."